# how to concatenate NSString and NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concatenation, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate a NSString with the NSString output of NSDateFormatter. My code is below.
Please check where I am going wrong. I have to concatenate *DEST PATH* with *datestring*.

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm"];

NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *DEST_PATH=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Movie1];

// below is for concatenate

result =[result stringByAppendingString:DEST_PATH];
result=[result stringByAppendingString:dateString];
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code other than you're missing the final quote mark after Movie1. What problem are you having (I assume that result is an empty string to start with)?

Comment: You could of course put all three append operations into one statement by using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/Movie1%@", NSHomeDirectory(), dateString]`.

Comment: ya...thanx for this info.. but Actually I need to concatenate in such a way that the path I have given (/document/movie1.mp3) with the date that is movie+date(then.mp3) so that each time when I save it gets different name

Comment: How is any of the other solutions proposed here not going to give you the "different name" you want, if you're appending the date/time in all cases??

Comment: Though minor technicality:  It's probably unwise to have a blank in the file name.  Put something other than blank between "yyyy" and "HH".

Comment: thanks ! It works!! one more thing .I am downloading a file by using NSURLConnection in a progress bar.Is it possible to PAUSE or STOP this file downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you never instantiate the `NSString` `result`. I would change the above to the following:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm"];
NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *DEST_PATH=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Movie1];
NSString* result=[DEST_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:dateString];
```

If you use the `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method it will automatically add the slash for you.

Also, using all capital letters for identifiers usually denotes a c style propocessor macro constant, so using it as a variable may confuse some people.

Comment: Right, as a general rule always use variable names starting with a lower-case letter.  For classes start with upper case.  Only for `#defines` (or perhaps other constants) should you use all caps.

Comment: ya...thanx for this info.. but Actually I need to concatenate in such a way that the path I have given (/document/movie1.mp3) with the date that is  
movie+date(then.mp3) 
so that each time when I save it gets different name.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm"];

NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *DEST_PATH=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/Movie1];

// below is for concatenate
  NSString *resultStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",DEST_PATH,dateString];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks ! It works!! one more thing .I am downloading a file by using NSURLConnection in a progress bar.Is it possible to PAUSE or STOP this file downloaded.